# How to get max min value in pandas dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Hi i got the data frame like this

```
import pandas as pd
data = [(1,"tom", 23),
        (1,"nick", 12),
        (1,"jim",13),
        (2,"tom", 44),
        (2,"nick", 56),
        (2,"jim",77),
        (3, "tom", 88),
        (3, "nick", 10),
        (3, "jim", 13),
        ]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['class', 'Name','number']
```

output of this dataframe

```
   class  Name  number
0      1   tom      23
1      1  nick      12
2      1   jim      13
3      2   tom      44
4      2  nick      56
5      2   jim      77
6      3   tom      88
7      3  nick      10
8      3   jim      1
```

how can i get the maximum number of in 3 different name of class 1 and get the number but in same name but different class the results can be look like this

```
[name =tom, class=1, number =23]
[name =tom, class=2, number =44]
[name =tom, class=3, number =88]
```

Thank you very much for helping me!

Comment: can you rewrite the description of what you want in a clearer way?

Answer (score 0):

Find the name first from class 1, and then filter:

```
name = df.Name.loc[df[df['class'] == 1].number.idxmax()]
df[df.Name == name]
#   class Name  number
#0      1  tom      23
#3      2  tom      44
#6      3  tom      88
```

Answer (score 0):

Try tis.

```
idx = df.groupby(['class'])['number'].transform(max) == df['number']
df[idx]
```

[image]